# Does wordnet directly present with similarity between synsets?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, text-analysis

I have come across several libraries that calculate the similarity between various synsets in Wordnet according to different algorithms. My basic question is whether Wordnet also provides a similarity measure between synsets, or is this similarity measure always calculated using some algorithm with a third party implementations?

Comment: The Wordnet is just a database, and it doesn't store any such measure directly in its tables

Comment: Because the number of similarities to count is N*N-1, so it's achievable but much will be redundant since many a times you don't want the similarity between all the synsets. often you only want the ones you're concerned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

See: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/documentation/

It's a great tool, but it's supposed to be used as a database.  The algorithms that calculate similarity are probably looking at the count and type of the various links between the synsets (there are many).